# Deja Dup - Should I backup hidden files located in home folder?

Tags: backup, deja-dup, hidden-files

I'm using Deja Dup in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I do a backup for /home contents once a week. What should I do with the hidden files that are being stored?
If unnecessary, how could tell Deja Dup to ignore them?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: They contain all your settings - do not ignore them!

Answer (score 0):

You should backup the hidden files that are in your home directory. Some of those files are configuration files for installed software, .bashrc, .viminfo, .vimrc, etc. Look for any .*rc files in your home directory, and you will see what I'm talking about.